# Subspace of complex space $\Bbb C^{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is 
>   $$L=\{(z_1,...,z_{2n}) \in \Bbb C^{2n}; \sum_{k=1}^n |z_k+z_{n+k}|=0\}$$
>   subspace of complex vector space $\Bbb C^{2n}$? If it is, find a base and dimension of it's direct complement.

How should I approach this problem?

At first I thought I should maybe write $|z_k+z_{n+k}|$ as $|a_k+ib_k+a_{n+k}+ib_{n+k}|=\sqrt {(a_k+a_{n+k})^2+(b_k+b_{n+k})^2} $ but I didn't know what to do from there.

Then, to prove that this is a subspace, I tried using $\alpha x+\beta y =0$, where $x=(a_1+b_1i,...,a_{2n}+b_{2n}i)$ and $y=(c_1+d_1i,...,c_{2n}+d_{2n}i)$. Then,  $\alpha x+\beta y =(\alpha a_1+\beta c_1 +i(\alpha b_1+\beta d_1),...,\alpha a_{2n}+\beta c_{2n} +i(\alpha b_{2n}+\beta d_{2n}))$. But then, again, I felt like I haven't actually done anything because I still didn't know what to do next. So, if anybody could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove it's a subspace, take any $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_{2n}),w=(w_1,\ldots,w_{2n})\in L$, and any $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{C}$. Then 
$$\alpha z+\beta w = (\alpha z_1+\beta w_1,\ldots,\alpha z_{2n}+\beta w_{2n})\,.$$
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|(\alpha z+\beta w)_k+(\alpha z+\beta w)_{n+k}|&=\sum_{k=1}^n|\alpha z_k + \beta w_k + \alpha z_{n+k} + \beta w_{n+k}| \\&\leq \alpha\sum_{k=1}^n |z_k+z_{n+k}|+\beta\sum_{k=1}^n|w_k+w_{n+k}|\\&=0
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, $\alpha z+\beta w\in L$.

Hint for finding the basis and dimension: $\sum_{k=1}^n|z_k+z_{n-k}|=0$ if and only if $|z_k+z_{n-k}|=0$ for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, if $|z_k+z_{n+k}|=0$, then $z_k=-z_{n+k}$, which means that $L=\{z_1,...,z_n,-z_1,...,-z_n\}$. Then the base for L is $\{e_k+e_{n+k},k=1,...,n\}$ and $dim L = n$, right?

Comment: Almost: the base is $\{e_k-e_{n+k}: k=1,\ldots,n\}$. Everything else is right